# 32.768 khz crystal for time base?

Tags: crystal, counter

I'm looking for a smallest design of a frequency counter time base uses a crystal with lower frequency that can give rates of 1Hz, 10Hz, 100Hz after dividing, I intend to use it in RF circuit, the reason for a lower frequency crystal is trying to avoid interference in the RF circuit, for example can the 32.768khz crystal, is it a better choice for the time base ? if not any other suggestions with help of a better design diagram ? I would appreciate it, thanks

Comment: While 32000Hz crystals aren't as popular as 32768Hz crystals, they manufactured as standard parts and should not be difficult to obtain.  Given a 32000Hz crystal, it should be easy to extract a 1000Hz signal and from there to use a couple of two-digit decimal counter chips to get stable outputs at power-of-ten frequencies.

Comment: In the UK you can find 60kHz crystals (thanks to its use as the MSF broadcast frequency reference. http://uk.farnell.com/citizen-finetech-miyota/cfv206-60-000kazf-ub/crystal-60k-12-5pf-cl-6x2mm-cyl/dp/1611704

Comment: You should tell us more about your counter. if mimimal space is the concern, an FPGA is the way to go, but I doubt that's in you budget. So, are you planning to use separate counter ICs and displays? How about displays with built-in counters? And how, exactly, do you plan to count RF frequencies? Even 100 MHz (American FM radio stations) will require a certain amount of competence. Or are you planning to use a divider chip to get down to a usable frequency?

Comment: *the reason for a lower frequency crystal is trying to avoid interference in the RF circuit* That is not by definition the best approach ! A squarewave signal of 32 kHz will contain a spur every 32 kHz. A 10 MHz one only every 10 MHz. Keep the rise/fall times under control as this determines how strong those spurs will be. Choosing the **right** crystal frequency is also crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you're most interested in reducing electromagnetic coupling from counter (and its display of frequency) to a RF-sensitive circuit (receiver?).
 The time-base oscillator is just one source of RF. Counter chains and display drivers are other radiating sources. Use a metal-case crystal (like HC-49) and ground its case.
[image: HC-49 crystal] Integrate your time base into a microcontroller that also drives the frequency display. A crystal-controlled microcontroller master clock can *also* serve as the counter's time base. The tiny microcontroller area is easy to isolate, bypass, and shield. Discrete counter chains of chips are to be avoided.
Use a LCD display of frequency, rather than LED or other high current displays. Transient currents to each LED segment radiate RF energy.
 Sometimes choosing a high-frequency crystal allows you to place its frequency in a remote out-of-the way spot that will cause you less grief. Harmonics of a low-frequency time base can cause grief over a w-i-d-e frequency range.